# Multiple route handlers in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my Backbone.js app, I have a route structure that has some common part which I'd like to handle in one handler only. For instance, these URLs

```
/#scenario/1/show-report
/#scenario/2/foo
/#scenario/3/bar
```

would all need to set the scenario to its particular identifier. At current, I do this in each route handler (in the handler for `show-report`, `foo` and `bar`). Is there any way of catching the URL up to `scenario/:id/`, calling the appropriate function and processing the rest by the specific handlers?

Answer (score 2):

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        'scenario/:id/:type' : 'scenario'
    },
    scenario : function (id, type) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'show-report': console.log('show-report'); break;
            case 'foo':         console.log('foo'); break;
            case 'bar':         console.log('bar'); break;
        }
    }
});

new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Thanks. This would work if it's only a few routes, but it's almost all the routes of the application and they are scattered in different modules which are quite isolated from each other.